# Why S̅=I(r) and S=I?

Tags: macroeconomics, economic-growth, financial-economics

Why is  S̅ constant when it's equal to I(r)?

Why is S inconstant when it's =I?

Thank you!

Comment: Please include some background to your question. What is S? What is I? What model are you studying? As far as I can tell your statements are inconsistent?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Context: Loanable funds market. S=Savings. I=Investment. Thanks!!